# How to create custom wallet for ERC20 tokens

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

I know metamask, MEW etc can be used, but how can I create a new wallet for an ERC20 token.

Having [NAME-OF-TOKEN Wallet].
Can generate new token address on sign up automatically.
Can send tokens from one address to another without having ETH deductions, unlike Metamask etc.
Hope to hear from anyone with answers, suggestions or links soonest.

Thank you!

Comment: where do you want to create wallet ? in code if so which language, please explain more

Comment: Am most fluent in java and I can easily pick up pace in javascript. However, I dont mind diving into other languages if need be or recommended. Hope to hear from you soon Ash.

Comment: I would also appreciate some details, links to help understand how it works

Comment: hello @asone, please can you help?